# What does the following code do in php?

Tags: php, variables

Please explain the following code. I can't understand what is happening.

```
return !$test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "!" is the 'NOT' operator.

the "return !$test" check the variable is not true (false). If $test is false then return true.

Ex:
!$a   >>>>  TRUE if $a is not TRUE.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Answer (score 6):

It returns the opposite boolean value of `$test`. If test is true, or anything that equates to true, it returns false. If it is false, or anything that equates to false, it returns true.

Comment: [More informations here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)

Comment: Let's vote to close this question.